# RHEL 8 install.log - where I can find this file?

Tags: rhel, logs

Where I can find this file titled `install.log`? It is usually located in the root home directory `/root`, but since release 8 it has been moved to other location. It contains information about the installation.

Answer (score 1):

The installation logs can be found in `/var/log/anaconda/`.

[Source](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Trouble-x86/#tabl-installation-log-files-x86).